# Determining locus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z+\bar{z}| =|z-\bar{z}|$ then determine the locus of $z$.

This is how I attempted it ,

The given statement implies that $z$ is equidistant from -$\bar{z}$ and $\bar{z}$ so it lies on the perpendicular bisector of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ which is a straight line.

However the solution of the given problem is as follows - 
 Let $z= x+iy$

$|z+\bar{z}| = |z-\bar{z}|$

Implies

$|2x| = |2y|$

$|x|=|y|$

Therefore $x=y$ or $x= -y$ which is a pair of straight lines.

Where did I go wrong ? Is it because a the definition of a perpendicular bisector is the locus of all those points which are equidistant from two fixed points ? But for a given $z$ , wouldn’t $\bar{z}$ and $-\bar{z}$ be fixed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The given statement implies that $z$ is equidistant from $-\bar{z}$ and $\bar{z}$ so it lies on the perpendicular bisector of $\ldots$

But $\,z\,$ is *the* variable in this case, so the perpendicular bisector of $\,\bar z\,$ and $\,-\bar z\,$ changes for each $\,z\,$.

Instead, use that $\,z+ \bar z = 2 \operatorname{Re}(z)\,$ and $\,z- \bar z = 2i \operatorname{Im}(z)\,$, then the equality reduces to:

$$\require{cancel}
|\operatorname{Re}(z)|=|\operatorname{Im}(z)|
$$

The latter is equivalent to $\,\operatorname{Re}(z)=\pm \operatorname{Im}(z)\,$, or $\,x=\pm y\,$ in Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

$z$ is not a constant in this problem...  thus neither are $\bar z$ and $-\bar z$...
That's where your error is.

For $z$ to satisfy the equation $\lvert z+\bar z\rvert=\lvert z-\bar z\rvert$, we need only $x=\pm y$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that

$$|z+\bar z|=|2Re(z)|$$

$$|z-\bar z|=|2Im(z)|$$

thus the locus $$|2x|=|2y|\iff|x|=|y|$$

is correct.

Indeed we can also write

$\left|\frac{z+\bar z}2\right|=\left|z-\frac{z-\bar z}2\right| \equiv$ distance of z from y axis

$\left|\frac{z-\bar z}2\right|=\left|z-\frac{z+\bar z}2\right|\equiv$ distance of z from x axis

thus the locus we are looking for are the bisectors.

Comment: Could you please explain where I was wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: @Aditi the condition $|z+\bar z|=|z-\bar z|$ doesn't mean that the distance is equal

Comment: oh Right !! Thank you

Comment: @gimusi `doesn't mean that the distance is equal` But yes, it means precisely that for each $\,z\,$, just as $\,|z-a|=|z-b|\,$ means that $\,z\,$ is equidistant from $\,a,b\,$ in general. Problem in OP's case is that $\,a,b\,$ were not *fixed* points, but varied with $\,z\,$ itself.

Comment: Aditi.For a second I was puzzled by your argument :Equidistant from 2 fixed points. plus minus  z (upper  bar) are NOT fixed points , as z varies so does z(upper bar):))

Comment: @dxiv Yes you are right of course! I mean that it doaesn't mean that z is equidistant from $\bar z$ and $-\bar z$ as stated.

Comment: @gimusi But $\,|z+\bar z| = |z-\bar z|\,$ ***does*** mean that $\,z\,$ is equidistant from $\,-\bar z\,$ and $\,\bar z\,$.

Comment: @dxiv ops of course I don't know what I was thinking about!

Comment: @dxiv actually $|z-\bar{z}|$ represents the  length of the resultant of the vectors $z$ and $-\bar{z}$ isn’t it ? I don’t think it represents the distance between them

Comment: @Aditi sorry I get confused dxiv if of course right, $|z-\bar z|$ is the distance between $z$ and $\bar z$ and  $|z+\bar z|$ is the distance between $z$ and $-\bar z$ and they are equal only if z belongs to the axes bisectors.

Comment: @Aditi Of course $\,z-\bar z\,$ represents the distance between $\,z\,$ and $\,\bar z\,$. In general,  $\,|a-b|\,$ represents the distance between $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$, just as $\,|c|\,$ represents the distance between $\,c\,$ and $\,0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv oh thank you ! But the prerequisite for it to represent the distance is that $\bar{z}$ should be fixed right ?

Comment: @Aditi There is no prerequsite for it. $\,|a-b|\,$ *always* represents the distance between $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$. What you derive from that, however, depends on your other assumptions. In the case of $\,a=z\,$ and $\,b=\bar z\,$, neither point is fixed, so you can't assume anything about their perpendicular bisector.

Comment: @dxiv in general , would , say $|z-2|$ represent the distance between $z$ and $2$ since $2$ is fixed ? I thought it represented the resultant of the vector $z$ and $-2$ just like $|\vec{r_1} - \vec{r_2}|$ represents the length of theresultant  of $\vec{r_1}$ And -$\vec{r_2}$

Comment: @Aditi `the resultant of the vector z and −2` That's the same as the diagonal between $\,z\,$ and $\,2\,$ if you draw the parallelograms. Just as $\,\overrightarrow{OA}-\overrightarrow{OB}=\overrightarrow{BA}\,$ in vector notation.

Comment: @dxiv okay thank you very much for clearing my doubt !!